# TYPO3 version 10 multidomain

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have just started working on TYPO3 10 and I'm looking to make 3 websites with different domain URLs.

In TYPO3 9, I usually define the domains using the "domain record" in the list module, but in TYPO3 10 I can't find it. It seems that the domain record is no longer available in TYPO3 10.

My issue is that each site is under the same domain with a predefined identifier, I would like to have a different domain for each website.

Can somebody explain how the multidomain works in TYPO3 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TYPO3 9, the domain handling has changed quite a lot. The new way to create multi-language and/or multi-domain setups is using site configurations. There's a new backend module called "Sites" where you can configure your domains and languages.

If you want to manage three different websites with three different domains, create three different site configurations in the "Sites" module.

You can find detailed informations in the [official TYPO3 docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Basics.html).

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, i will check it out.